# jtable update data not visible

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, jtable, event-dispatch-thread

I am running into a problem similar to what I have read here about inserted data and added data not showing up on jtable. I have tried repaint() and revalidate(), but to no avail.

Basically, I have two classes say A and B. A calls a function in class B to add a row of data to the table. Here is the code.(By the way I am using Netbeans 7.1.2 to add a table and then add some code to handle the update.)

```
public void callUpdateTable(){
    DefaultTableModel myModel = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
    DateFormat dateFormate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Object[] str = new Object[3];
    Date date = new Date();  

    str[0] = dateFormate.format(date);
    str[1] = "Robot";
    str[2] = "hello"; 
    // myModel.addRow(str);
    myModel.insertRow(1, str);
    myModel.setValueAt("Hello", 1, 2);
    System.out.println("count = " + myModel.getValueAt(1, 2));
    jTable1.repaint();
}
```

The funny thing is on system print it prints out the value at the cell(1,2) I set the value, but doesn't show up on the table. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that the JTable you're changing the data on, jTable1, is the same JTable instance that is being displayed? My experience here has shown that errors like this one are often due to one of mistaken references. Note that your post and code don't tell us nearly enough to be able to give you an answer with confidence. You need to ask a better more informative question -- unless someone makes a lucky guess.

Answer (score 4):

It is best if you can compose an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

There is no need to call `repaint()/revalidate()`. As a result of `insertRow()` the model will trigger table refresh by executing `fireTableRowsInserted()`.

`DefaultTableModel` uses `vector` which has zero based index. `insertRow()` calls into [Vector.insertElementAt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#insertElementAt%28E,%20int%29) which throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if index is out of range.

Assuming that your model is empty, try this:

```
myModel.insertRow(0, str);
```

Also, make sure you interact with the table on [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).